# Samsung keyboard issue comma is not showing

Tags: android

[image]

I am trying to show comma when user click on edittext but it is not showing in samsung devices except it it is working but not showing comma i have assign inputvalue is 0123456789,
in xml as well as in java code(Activity) also and input type is

```
 android:digits="0123456789,"
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

please change

```
android:digits="0123456789," 
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

with this

`android:inputType="phone"
android:digits="0123456789,"`

It will show and accept, on symbol hope this answer will help you

Comment: Does not work on latest Samsung devices